# Prevent CXCallController from appearing if a call has already been answered

Tags: swift, callkit

In my app, I have a custom button that starts a call. The call's UI is handled in CallProvider delegate method and works correctly.
However, once the call is answered by my custom button before CXCallController is showed on the screen and UI is opened, the CXCallController also appears and that is not needed any longer.
So my question is there any way how to prevent CXCallController from appearing in this case?

```
func startCall() {
    let handle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: UUID())
    let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: call.id, handle: handle)
    startCallAction.isVideo = true

    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)
    callController.request(transaction) { [weak self] (error) in
        if let error = error {
           // error handling
        } else {
          // something
        }
    }
}
```